# How to Query a MySQL database and display results using a dropdown in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to query a MySQL database and display the results on a php webpage as below ,

[image] however i get the error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'position' (T_STRING) in C:\wamp64\www\webform\display-data.php on line 5.Below is my PHP code

```
<?php 
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost','staff','staff','webform');
$query ="SELECT position FROM entries";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if($result->num_rows> 0){
  $options= mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
<?php 


<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
include("fetch-data.php");
?>
<select name="position">
   <option>Select staff</option>
  <?php 
  foreach ($options as $option) {
  ?>
    <option><?php echo $option['position']; ?> </option>
    <?php 
    }
   ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Missing closing quote in `include("fetch-data.php);`

Comment: Hello, that was a typo on my side the original code did not have the error, ,I still cannot display the results –

Comment: Don't _type_ code here, use copy/paste - for exact that reason. Any other typo in your code here? Where/how do you submit your ... where is your form? Where are you trying to get the dropdown value?

Comment: Please follow my code you will get result
As i provide you file name and also provide file code how to follow it.

Answer (score 0):

Move option tag inside your echo so it should be like this:

```
<select name="position">
   <option>Select staff</option>
   <?php 
       foreach ($options as $option) {
          echo "<option>$option['position'];</option>";
       }
   ?>
</select>
```

That should echo option tag for each $option. You can also add value attribute by adding `value='$option['position'];'`

Answer (score -2):

```
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
include("fetch-data.php");

echo'<select name="position">
 <option>Select staff</option>'; 
  foreach ($options as $option) { 
   echo'<option value='.$option['position'].'>'.$option['position'].'</option>';
  } 
echo'</select>';
```

?>

Answer (score -2):

I just found your problem. Just separate your file as my below code and check.

```
<!-- Database connection file code (dbconfig.php) -->
<?php
// $mysqli=mysqli_connect(hostname, username, password, databaname)
$mysqli = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'staff', 'staff', 'webform');
?>

<!-- Fetch data file code (fetch-data.php) -->
<?php
$query = "SELECT position FROM entries";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $options = mysqli_fetch_all($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
?>

<!-- Your display dropdown file (index.php) -->
<?php
include("dbconfig.php");
include("fetch-data.php");
?>

<select name="position">
    <option>Select staff</option>
    <?php
    foreach ($options as $option) {
    ?>
        <option><?php echo $option['position']; ?> </option>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: FYI you never need a greeting in a question or answer (I removed it from your question). More importantly: you need to explain *why* your answer solves the OP's question. At a quick glance, it's not obvious that there's anything different, other than separating sections (which doesn't solve any problem).

Comment: Understood, thank you for the feedback. I will make sure to include more context and explain the relevance of my answers to the original question in the future.